# Use id and version columns to map one-to-many relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, version, one-to-many

I have two JPA entities, `Parent` and `Child`.

Parent has an `@Id` and a `@Version`.

For each parent (id and version as FKs) there are multiple children.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "parent")
public class ParentDao implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "parent_id")
    private Long parentId;

    @Version
    @Column(name = "parent_version", updatable = false)
    private Long parentVersion;

...
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "child")
public class ChildDao implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "child_id")
    private Long childId;

    @Column(name = "parent_id", updatable = false)
    private Long parentId;

    @Column(name = "parent_id", updatable = false)
    private Long parentVersion;

...
}
```

If the version would not have a constraint, a FK in the child towards parent, the relation would have been.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parentId", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<ChildDao> children = new HashSet<>(0);
```

Hibernate treats the version as a special field since there is the `@Version` annotation set at the attribute level.

So from this, I can imagine that maybe they thought of this when implementing the one-to-many relation.

Nonetheless, there might be a more generic solution.

**So, how can I add the version as a constraint in the one to many relation?**

Answer (score 2):

In a RDBMS, the FK references the PK. So, the Child FK must reference the Parent entity identifier, right?

The `version` should never form the FK because the version keeps on changing, while the FK should not since it must reference a *immutable* FK.

If you need a custom way of expressing a collection, then you should use [`@JoinFormla` instead of `@JoinColumn`](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-customize-an-entity-association-join-on-clause-with-hibernate-joinformula/).

More, the `Child` mapping is wrong anyway since you are duplicating the `parent_id` mapping:

```
@Column(name = "parent_id", updatable = false)
private Long parentId;

@Column(name = "parent_id", updatable = false)
private Long parentVersion;
```

Maybe you wanted to have:

```
@Column(name = "parent_id", updatable = false)
private Long parentId;

@Column(name = "parent_version", updatable = false)
private Long parentVersion;
```

Comment: A) Id and version is a the PK of the parent, I cannot change that. Parent with id=1 and version=1 is a different parent the parent with id=1 and version=2.           B) parent_id its just a typo in the post. Hibernate doesn't let you map the same column under two annotations anyways.                                                                   
   C) the version column/field can be seen as any other one field/column, just that we have @Session in JPA, i thought that it might have support in onetomany relation.

Comment: Well, your design will not work because once you modify the entity, it's PK will change, right? That's not how PK are supposed to work. PKs are meant to be immutable.

Comment: well, no. When the PK changes (version changes), a new entity is created, rendering the old one obsolete, but still valid. This design does not really matter if its valid or not from any point of view, what matters really if there is any way a one-to-many (unidirectional if possible) relation can have two "join columns".